# Improving performance of infinite scrolling animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, anime.js

I have long list of elements with svg icons(60-70 elements) and I want to animate it so it looks like infinite scrolling. I am using animejs  library and animating `translateY` property of the `g` group which contains all elements. This works ok but performance is not very good. I am already using `will-change: transform` CSS attribute for the `g` tags which are being animated. I am animating just single `translateY` transform, why is performance so poor? How can I improve performance?

I could try to have only elements required to cover the screen and then animate these elements instead. But that would require constantly changing "src" attribute of the elements which come from off screen and I feel like would be even slower. 
Should I replace SVG icons with png? I feel like this should not affect animation performance.
Unfortunately I can't use CSS animations because I need to sync this animation with some other animations on the page.

```js
    let initialOffset = 0;
    let currentOffset = 0;
    anime({
        target: '.group-of-boxes',
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        loop: true,
        loopBegin: function(anim) {
            initialOffset = currentOffset;
        },
        update: function(anim) {
            const d = 100 * anim.progress / 100;
            currentOffset = clipOffset(initialOffset + d, object);
            anime.set(target , {
                translateY: currentOffset
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post a mini version of your script so we could inspect the problem.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with my current code. What I want to know is what would be the best practice to achieve this kind of animation for best possible performance.

Comment: Now i see the code, it was not there before, but its still not a mini version. add a working mini version if its possible